# error: cannot access zzbgl error keep re-appearring

Tags: android, firebase

I'm creating a Uber-like app. So you can imagine the user will be able to log in using facebook/google/firebase for those using phone numbers.

The code is fine as it was used before, however I lost the previous project's gradle settings. as such now I am faced with error message

> error: cannot access zzbgl class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

please help me.

I have isolated the problem. if I delete all firebase related codes, I wouldnt have this issue.

FirebaseAuth, FirebaseUser etc.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sunshinetechie.gethitched"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    /*androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'*/
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:+'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:+'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:+'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'


    implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'


}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: it still doesnt work. i tried various versions

Comment: any update? I have tried regenerating SHA-1 key, API key and so on